Winter Bash 2013

This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users
  will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
  That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and
  other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
  hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
  available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all
  hats will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
  the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.
All responses will need to be in by 1 December 2013. Sites that
  haven’t responded by then will be considered to have opted out from
  the event.


I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Winter Bash 2014 happened over a year ago.

Last years Winter Bash was successful and I'd like to see it return this winter.

Fun was had collecting hats ;)

Three up votes - Ambo100 are you going to reply back with a "yes" then?

@Zhaph-BenDuguid Sorry, I've replied with a yes, we are set for Winterbash 2013.

Sweet :) Here come the hats!
